# Does reducing the number of executor-cores consume less executor-memory?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

My Spark job failed with the YARN error `Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits 10.0 GB of 10 GB physical memory used`.

Intuitively, I decreased the number of cores from `5` to `1` and the job ran successfully.

I did not increase the `executor-memory` because `10g` was the max for my YARN cluster.

I just wanted to confirm if my intuition. Does reducing the number of `executor-cores` consume less `executor-memory`? If so, why?

Comment: The number of executor-cores specifies how many jobs can be run per executor. So when you had 5 cores, each executor attempted to run at most 5 jobs at the same time. If each job was attempting to get to 10g, then you would attempt to be using 50g of RAM for a single job. By reducing the number to of cores to 1, each executor will only use 10g RAM. https://mapr.com/blog/resource-allocation-configuration-spark-yarn/

Comment: @bogertron I thought it was the opposite - in that the number of cores would share the `executor-memory` per executor. For ex, in my original case if `executor-memory` was `10g` and `exectuor-cores` was 5, so all 5 cores would share the 10g memory. Is that a fair statement?

Comment: I apologize, and you are correct. As for the question you posed, you are running 5 parallel calculations (or threads) at most. Even if you attempt to share memory across the threads, there will be additional overhead for each running task in the memory space that is allocated for the executor

Comment: How many nodes do you have in the cluster? Did you set `num-executors`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
spark.executor.cores = 5, spark.executor.memory=10G
```

This means an executor can run 5 tasks in parallel. That means 10 GB needs to be shared by 5 tasks.So effectively on an average - each task will have 2 GB available. If all the tasks consumes more than 2 GB, than overall JVM will end up consuming more than 10 GB and so YARN will kill the container.

```
spark.executor.cores = 1, spark.executor.memory=10G
```

This means an executor can run only 1 task. That means 10 GB is available to 1 task completely. So if the task uses more than 2 GB but less than 10 GB, it will work fine. That was the case in your Job and so it worked.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, each executor uses an extra 7% of memoryOverhead.

This calculation will be created thinking that you have two nodes, so we have three executors in one node and two executors in the other node.

```
Memory per executor in the first node = 10GB/3 = 3,333GB
Counting off heap overhead = 7% of 3,333GB = 0,233GB. 

So, your executor-memory should be 3,333GB - 0,233GB = 3,1GB per node
```

You can read another explanation here:
https://spoddutur.github.io/spark-notes/distribution_of_executors_cores_and_memory_for_spark_application.html